# Compact Framework MessageBox: change button focus

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, compact-framework

I'm working on a Windows CE project and have run into a strange problem. When i display a messagebox the physical key stop working. The project relies solely on key input which work fine when changing focus between objects on the form. Because i can't slect an option from the message box, the application basically locks out.
I initially thought my keydown handler was to blame but i discovered the same issue regardless of the keydown handler (even in a new project it doesn't work)
I've been looking around online for information but the only thing i've come across involves changing messagebox buttons. The most prominent solution is to create your own messageboxes but it seems like a waste for what i need. Is there a more efficient way of solving this problem?

Comment: can you share the code?